# Почему код не выдает NOTICE?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему сей код не выдает NOTICE?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$v = NULL;

echo $v[0];
```

Соответственно, если $v не объявлять как NULL, то будет Notice: Undefined variable: v in

Спасибо.

Comment: Переменная определена, поэтому никаких нотисов быть не должно.

P.S. 

    $null = NULL; // эта переменная определена, как NULL 
    $empty = ""; // определены, но "empty"
    $true = TRUE; // определена, не NULL и "notempty"
    unset($undefined); // эта переменная не определена

Comment: Ты можешь применять операцию вывода echo или взятия индекса к любым объектам, даже к NULL. Правда применять операции к не инициализированным(там где нет равно), а соответственно не существующим переменным, нельзя.

Comment: @Deonis, NULL[0], по-моему, должен выдавать вполне себе четкую ошибку, что null - не переменная c array access. Хотя у меня возвращает NULL. Забавная штука.

Comment: @Etki, в это парадокс я не вникал. Хотя, если мы к любому значению (string, array) можем обратиться по индексу, то почему бы к значению "ничего" нельзя так же обратиться? **"ничего"[100500]** - всё равно "**ничего**". Бред, наверно, но по-другому объяснить не берусь. ))

Comment: Мне кажется, что все простые типы наследуются от одного класса Object, в котором по умолчанию уже заложено правильное поведение для обращения по индексу. Иначе бы с чего бы такому коду внезапно работать?

        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $v = NULL;

        $v[0] = "~oh shi";
        echo $v[0]; //Внезапно выводит ~oh shi

        $b = NULL;

        $b["Chock-chock"] = "Hi ;)";
        echo $b["Chock-chock"]; //Уже не настолько внезапно выводит Hi ;) 

Но искать истину я оставлю кому-нибудь другому,у кого есть желание копать исходники.

Comment: @Alex Krass

> Мне кажется, что все простые типы наследуются от одного класса Object

Нет, это не так, PHP к ООП пришел не сразу. Про внутреннюю кухню можно почитать [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/226707/) и [здесь](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php).

> в котором по умолчанию уже заложено правильное поведение для обращения по индексу

Объекты не реализуют обращения по индексу по умолчанию. С NULL особая ситуация в том плане, что у него значение не выставляется - проверяется тип, и переменная сразу считается за NULL. Так что это что-то вроде незакрытой дырки.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался довольно простым. Когда PHP что-то не нравится, он конвертирует тип. При чем разобраться, когда это преобразование на лету является валидным, а когда невалидным, представляется невозможным. Короче:

> Converting NULL to an array results in an empty array.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

и еще забавная строчка оттуда же:

> Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".

При попытке выставить индекс PHP смотрит на переменную, находит `NULL`, считает его эквивалентным `array`, преобразует в пустой массив и проставляет значение. Уведомление не появляется, потому что по философии разработчиков `NULL` идентичен `array`. А ведь могли бы и запилить.

Доказательство:

```
$a = null;
$a[0] = 'What the hell?';
var_dump(null == array(), $a == null, gettype($a), $a);
/*
    bool(true)
    bool(false)
    string(5) "array"
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      string(14) "What the hell?"
    }
*/
```

p.s. хотя все равно непонятно, почему доступ к несуществующему индексу не сопровождается уведомлением.

p.p.s. уиииииииииииииииииииии

```
$varA = null;
for ($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
    $varA = $varA[$i];
    // $varB = null[$i]; // вот заметьте, здесь он ругнется на невалидный синтаксис
}
var_dump($varA /*, $varB*/);
```